# Data Pipelines not available

Tags: acumos

When I open *Home / Design Studio / ML Workbench / **Data Pipelines***

An error occurred:

*Server is not available.Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 10.104.209.167:9090*

PS:

VMWare Ubuntu16.04 64bit

AIO 3.0.1

All k8s pods running successfully, and all docker images up successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If possible could you please share the logs for the Data Pipeline error "Server not available"

Command : 
kubectl logs  -n youracumosnamespace mlwb-pipeline-IDofpipelinepod